# Loading CakePHP application from outside document root

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, alias

I'm trying to load a CakePHP application from another document root.

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName internet.com
    DocumentRoot "/sites/internet"

    ...

    Alias /developer "/sites/intranet/developer"

</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I visit `internet.com/developer/cakeapp/portal`, I get a 404. If I visit `intranet.com/developer/cakeapp/portal`, it works.

Working configuration for the intranet site:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName intranet.com
        DocumentRoot "/sites/intranet"

            ...

        <Directory "/sites/intranet/developer/cakeapp">
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteBase /developer/cakeapp
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !OPTIONS
              RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/index.php?url=$2 [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Should I include the mod_rewrites in the internet VirtualHost configuration too? I had assume that they would translate when the intranet site would be accessed.

Note: this setup is on a development server that is configured to mimic both intranet and internet hosting. The goal is to reuse the portal site on both domains.

**Update #1**

Using Cake 2.4.5

**Update #2**

Looking at my SSL error log file, I noticed this:
`File does not exist: /sites/intranet/developer/cakeapp/users`

The app redirects to `users/login`, so it would seem that some of this is working. Still doesn't explain the 404.

**Update #3**

New rewrite rules being used:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /developer/cakeapp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @mark see update, 2.4.5...

Comment: Also, your RewriteRule looks quite old. See the cakephp repo code on how it should look like in 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the configuration that works. I had to duplicate some configuration elements from the intranet configuration, which I thought would have been applied during the aliasing process.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName internet.com
    DocumentRoot "/sites/internet"

    ...

    Alias /developer "/sites/intranet/developer"

    <Directory "/sites/intranet/developer">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /developer/cakeapp
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```